# How does a language talk to hardware?

Tags: c++, assembly, hardware

Ok so I'm very very confused how a piece of hardware can understand code.
I read somewhere it has to do with voltages but how exactly does the piece of hardware know what an instruction in software means? I know drivers is the bridge between software and hardware but a driver is still software :S.

For example, in C++ we have pointers and they can point to some address in memory.. Can we have a pointer that points to some hardware address and then write to that address and it would affect the hardware? Or does hardware not have addresses?

I guess what I'm really asking is how does the OS or BIOS know where a piece of hardware is and how to talk to it?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I feel it's too broad to be answered on stackoverflow.

Comment: There's a few very different questions here. One is about how a CPU really works - for which you'll need a course in digital logic - and then some - there are courses which teach you how to construct your own CPU on FPGAs which will teach how a CPU actually works. The other, which is how a specific hardware can be addressed or communicated with that is a very different question: (e.g. yes, some hardware is mapped right into memory address space, with controllers translating memory requests onto hardware buses. And CPUs might have special instructions to manipulate I/O pins on the CPU)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, in C++ we have pointers and they can point to some
>   address in memory.. Can we have a pointer that points to some hardware
>   address and then write to that address and it would affect the
>   hardware? Or does hardware not have addresses?

Some hardware have addresses like pointers, some doesn't (In which case it most likely uses something called I/O ports, which requires special IN and OUT instructions instead of the regular memory operations). But much of the modern hardware has a memory address somewhere, and if you write the correct value to the correct address the hardware will do what you ask it to do. This varies from the really simple approach - say a serial port where you write a byte to an "output register", and the byte is sent along the serial line, and another address holds the input data being received on the serial port, to graphics cards that have a machine language of their own and can run hundreds or thousands of threads.

And normally, it's the OS's responsibility, via drivers, to access the hardware.

This is very simplified, and the whole subject of programming, OS and hardware is enough to write a fairly thick book about (and that's just in general terms, if you want to actually know about specific hardware, it's easily a few dozen pages for a serial port, and hundreds or thousands of pages for a graphics chip).

Answer (score 2):

There are whole books on this topic. But briefly:

- SW talks to hardware in a variety of ways. A given piece of hardware may respond to values written to very specific addresses ("memory mapped") or via I/O ports and instructions supported by the CPU (e.g., x86 instruction `in` and `out` instructions). When accessing a memory mapped port (address), the HW is designed to recognize the specific address or small range of addresses and route the signals to the peripheral hardware rather than memory in that case. Or in the case of I/O instructions, the CPU has a separate set of signals used specifically for that purpose.
- The OS (at the lowest level - board support package) and BIOS have "knowledge" built in to them about the hardware address and/or the I/O ports needed to execute the various hardware functions available. That is, at some level, they have coded in exactly what addresses are needed for the different features.

Comment: Ohh so does the hardware have to constantly check for a signal? Like a one or a zero? Or does the one or zero just turn into a voltage signal somehow and then the hardware reacts to that?

Comment: The one or zero always was a voltage (except perhaps during the transfer through an optical fiber or something). There is a pattern of voltages causing the text you write to be displayed on a screen, and this pattern can be translated into another one that can be interpreted by a CPU.

Comment: @CantChooseUsermames: In digital circuits 1/0 corresponds to voltages. For example voltage < 0.2 volts can be zero, and voltage > 1.5 volts can be one. It depends on circuit, and I don't know modern accepted values for voltages. If you're asking this kind of question, perhaps you should investigate zx spectrum schematics or attempt build a flip-flop/multivibrator using soldering iron and logic gate chip. That would clear things up.

Comment: @SigTerm: Modern electronics dropped the notion of a single logical voltage level for all components. It's just too inefficient to run everything at ~5 Volt. E.g. DDR3 has specs for 1.5 V and 1.35 V because that's best suited for memory chips close to a CPU, but USB runs at 5V to allow longer cables.

Comment: @MSalters: Well, I suspected this was the case (which is why I wrote "it depends on the chip").

Comment: ccu, yes the hardware is constantly checking for a signal.  It is driven by the clock so some of the hardware responds to that and samples other items.  Then when it sees the signals that indicate a command, read or write for example.  Then it responds to those.

Comment: @dwelch, it may be driven by a clock. Some signals are events which can be asynchronous to the clock.

Comment: absolutely.  Just trying to get the OP over the hump of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [The soul of new machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soul_of_a_New_Machine), by Tracy Kidder. It's a 1981 Pullitzer price and it goes to great length to explain in layman terms how a computer works and how humans must think to create it. Besides, it's a real story and one of the few to convey the thrill of hardware and software.
All in all, a nice introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware engineers know where the memory and peripherals live in the processors address space.  So it is something that is known because those addresses were chosen by someone and documented so that others could write drivers.

The processor does not know peripherals from ram.  The instructions are simply using addresses ultimately determined by the programmers that wrote the software that the processor is running.  So that implies, correctly, that the peripherals and ram (and rom) are all just addresses.  If you were writing a video driver and were changing the resolution of the screen, there would be a handful of addresses that you would need to write to.  At some point between the processor core and the peripheral (the video card) there would be hardware that examines the address and basically routes it to the right place.  This is how the hardware was designed, it examines addresses, some address ranges are ram and sent to the memory to be handled and some are peripherals and sent there to be handled.   Sometimes the memory ranges are programmable themselves so that you can organize your memory space for whatever reason.  Similar to if you move from where you are living now to somewhere else, it is still you and your stuff at the new house, but it has a different address and the postal folks who deliver the mail know how to find your new address.  And then there are MMU's that add a layer of protection and other features.  The MMU (memory management unit) can also virtualize an address, so the processor may be programmed to write to address 0x100000 but the mmu translates that to 0x2300000 before it goes out on the normal bus to be sorted as memory or peripheral eventually finding its destination.  Why would you do such a thing, well two major reasons.  One is so that for example when you compile an application to run in your operating system, all programs for that OS can be compiled to run at the same address lets say address 0x8000.  But there is only one physical address 0x8000 out there (lets assume) what happens is the operating system has configured the mmu for your program such that your program things it is running at that address, also the operating system can, if it chooses and the mmu has the feature, to add protections such that if your program tries to access something outside its allocated memory space then a fault occurs and your program is prevented from doing that.  Prevented from hacking into or crashing other programs memory space.  Likewise if the operating system supports it could also choose to use that fault to swap out some data from ram to disk and then give you more ram, virtual memory, allowing the programs to think there is more memory than there really is.  An mmu is not the only way to do all of this but it is the popular way.  So when you have that pointer in C++ running on some operating system it is most likely that that is a virtual address not the physical address, the mmu converts that address that has been given to your program into the real memory address.  When the os chooses to switch out your program for another it is relatively easy to tell the mmu to let the other task think that that low numbered address space 0x8000 for example now belongs to the other program.  And your program is put to sleep (not executed) for a while.